# Assessing performance of an agent based on commission rate, market share and revenue

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, decision-trees, scoring

I have a set of data for agents selling properties (apartments) for a company in different states. The company would like to assess the performance of the different agents given the following:

- Number of apartments sold
- Market share (%)
- Total Revenue
- Commission Rate (%)

In each state, there are a number of agents working for the company. Of course we would like to keep the agents that are bringing more revenue, selling more apartments, having greater market share and lower commission rate. However I am not sure how to tackle this four dimensional problem in the simplest possible way. I would like to give a score of 10 for each of the agents based on his performance. After that I will like to discard some of the under-performing agents in each state. Any clue from where to start?